# How can I watch an empty GitHub repository?

Tags: github

To watch a GitHub repository, I simply click on `watch`. E.g., from https://github.com/adobe-research/custom-diffusion:

[image]

I don't see the watch button in this empty GitHub repository https://github.com/adobe-research/meetingqa:

[image]

I am assuming, perhaps incorrectly, that it's because the GitHub repository is empty. How can I watch an empty GitHub repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### GitHub Activity Notifications

1. GitHub sets your default `notification` level for all repositories to include:

   - @mentions
   - Assignments
   - Commits you author or commit
   - Any discussion you've commented on
2. When you click on the `Watch` button, it is equivalent to changing the `notification` level for that particular repository to `All Activity`.
3. If, instead of clicking `Watch`, you were to open its drop-menu, you would see various `notification` levels, and selecting `All Activity` is equivalent to clicking `Watch`

   [image]
4. Any repositories with the `notification` level set to `All Activity` will show in your [GitHub Watching](https://github.com/watching) list.
5. As you noted, the Web App's GUI doesn't include the `Watch` button nor apparently any other way to set the `notification` level to `All Activity` for an empty repository.

### Workarounds

Despite the web app's lack of an interface customizing `notification` options for empty repositories is actually supported by the underlying code and can be accessed using the following approaches:

1. Github's mobile application includes the `notification` menu when the repository is empty ([Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.android) | [IOS](https://apps.apple.com/app/github/id1477376905?ls=1))

   [image]
2. GitHub's REST API allows subscribing to `All Activity` notifications for empty repositories:  [Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/activity/watching)

Answer (score -1):

2 other workarounds from [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-watch-an-empty-GitHub-repository/answer/Qasim-Raza-294), written by Qasim Raza:

> - Subscribe to the repository's RSS feed. This will send you an RSS feed notification whenever the repository is updated.
> - Use a third-party service like GitHub Alerts to monitor the repository for changes